# Why I cannot view the Flink metrics on the Prometheus dashboard?

Tags: java, apache-flink, prometheus

I configured Apache Flink to send metrics to Prometheus through the `conf/flink-conf.yaml` file:

```
metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
metrics.reporter.prom.host: 192.168.56.1
metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9250-9260
```

then I configured Prometheus on the file `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']
  - job_name: 'flink'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['jobmanager:9250', 'taskmanager1:9251', 'taskmanager2:9252']
```

The log of the first task manager says that Prometheus is configured:

```
2019-03-29 17:04:57,347 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: metrics.reporter.prom.class, org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
2019-03-29 17:04:57,348 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: metrics.reporter.prom.host, 192.168.56.1
2019-03-29 17:04:57,349 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: metrics.reporter.prom.port, 9250-9260
...
2019-03-29 17:04:59,463 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl           - Configuring prom with {port=9250-9260, host=192.168.56.1, class=org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter}.
2019-03-29 17:04:59,479 INFO  org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter        - Started PrometheusReporter HTTP server on port 9251.
2019-03-29 17:04:59,479 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl           - Reporting metrics for reporter prom of type org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter.
```

O copied the jar file `flink-metrics-prometheus_2.11-1.7.2.jar` to the `lib` directory of both nodes of my FLink instance. And I have a RichMapper class which exposes a Counter and a Meter. Why Can I not see the metrics on Prometheus dashboard?

I deply my application using this command `./bin/flink run -c org.sense.flink.App ../../../felipe/eclipse-workspace/explore-flink/target/explore-flink.jar 14 192.168.56.20 &` and I do can see the output on one of the taskmanager logs.

```
public static class SensorTypeMapper
        extends RichMapFunction<MqttSensor, Tuple2<CompositeKeySensorType, MqttSensor>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4080196110995184486L;

    private transient Counter counter;
    private transient Meter meter;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        this.counter = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().counter("counterSensorTypeMapper");

        com.codahale.metrics.Meter dropwizardMeter = new com.codahale.metrics.Meter();
        this.meter = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().meter("meterSensorTypeMapper",
                new DropwizardMeterWrapper(dropwizardMeter));
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple2<CompositeKeySensorType, MqttSensor> map(MqttSensor value) throws Exception {
        this.meter.markEvent();
        this.counter.inc();
        // every sensor key: sensorId, sensorType, platformId, platformType, stationId
        // Integer sensorId = value.getKey().f0;
        String sensorType = value.getKey().f1;
        Integer platformId = value.getKey().f2;
        // String platformType = value.getKey().f3;
        Integer stationId = value.getKey().f4;
        CompositeKeySensorType compositeKey = new CompositeKeySensorType(stationId, platformId, sensorType);
        return Tuple2.of(compositeKey, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. I just have to configure the correct hostname on the `targets` property of the file `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']   
  - job_name: 'flink'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9250', 'localhost:9251', '192.168.56.20:9250']
```